# Prefer node via direct connection over longer path

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

My graph model should allow inheriting attributes from a parent to a child and to override such inherited attributes on the child. Attributes are nodes that are attached with a `HAS` relationship.

```
CREATE (parent:Node {id: "P"})-[:HAS {inherited: true}]->(:Attribute:Name {value: "Indirect Name"})
CREATE (parent)-[:HAS]->(:Attribute:Other {value: "Other Attribute"})

CREATE (c1:Node {id: "C1"})-[:HAS]->(:Attribute:Name {value: "Direct Name"})
CREATE (c1)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(parent)
CREATE (c2:Node {id: "C2"})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(parent)
```

In this example we have `C1-[:BELONGS_TO]->P` and `C2-[:BELONGS_TO]->P`. `P` has defined an attribute `Name` that is inherited and an attribute `Other`, which is not inherited. `C1` has overriden the `Name` attribute, whereas `C2` inherits the attribute.

[image: example graph]

I now want to find all relevant attributes that belong to a certain node: the directly attached name attribute for C1 and the indirect name attribute for C2. The "other" attribute should not be considered for C1 and C2 because it's not inherited.

To get all direct and inherited attributes I can use this query:

```
MATCH (c {id: "C1"})-[:HAS]->(directAttribute:Attribute), (c)-[]->(:Node)-[:HAS{inherited: true}]->(inheritedAttribute:Attribute) RETURN directAttribute, inheritedAttribute
```

But this will obviously return both `Name` attributes, the one from `C1` and the inherited from `P`. How can we "prefer" the attributes that are directly attached to a node over the inherited one, so that in this case ony the "direct" name attribute is returned by a query?

Answer (score 2):

Using node labels to distinguish between attribute names is pretty unwieldy for your use case. I would suggest making the attribute name a property name instead. For example, as `name` and `other` in the following data creation query (along with `foo`, to show how to have multiple inherited attributes):

```
CREATE (parent:Node {id: "P"})-[:HAS {inherited: true}]->(:Attribute {name: "Indirect Name", foo: "Bar"})
CREATE (parent)-[:HAS]->(:Attribute {other: "Other Attribute"})

CREATE (c1:Node {id: "C1"})-[:HAS]->(:Attribute {name: "Direct Name"})
CREATE (c1)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(parent)
CREATE (c2:Node {id: "C2"})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(parent)
```

Then, you can use the convenient APOC function [apoc.map.merge](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/data-structures/map-functions/#map-functions) to get the applicable attributes for a `Node` (being careful to pass the "direct" attributes as the second argument).

For example, if you use this query for "C1":

```
MATCH (c:Node {id: "C1"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:HAS]->(da:Attribute)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:BELONGS_TO]->()-[:HAS {inherited: true}]->(ia:Attribute)
RETURN c, apoc.map.merge(ia, da) AS attrs
```

the result is:

```
╒═══════════╤══════════════════════════════════╕
│"c"        │"attrs"                           │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════════════════════╡
│{"id":"C1"}│{"name":"Direct Name","foo":"Bar"}│
└───────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘
```

The same query for "C2" gets this result:

```
╒═══════════╤════════════════════════════════════╕
│"c"        │"attrs"                             │
╞═══════════╪════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"id":"C2"}│{"name":"Indirect Name","foo":"Bar"}│
└───────────┴────────────────────────────────────┘
```

*You may also want to use a different relationship type (e.g., `[:INHERITS]`) in place of `[:HAS {inherited: true}]`.*

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start. When I add another "parent" to e.g. C1 `(C1)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(P2)` this query returns c multiple times with different sets of attributes. How can I then merge all the attributes?

Comment: BTW: Why is labelling different types of attributes not a good fit for this usecase?